# Assigning the values of Managed column into another field in Search query

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, enterprise-search, people-search, managed-property, search-query

I have a List with the managed column "Finance" which contains the list of finance departments.

I need to check if User's department belongs to any of the values in the "Finance" list.I am using Search webpart.

So how can I implement this scenario in query box of search webpart.
Can anyone suggest the ideas or answers?